# Drag'n'drop добавление материла

Tags: javascript, drag-n-drop

Есть ли такой плагин, с помощью которого можно перетаскивать элемента списка и при отпускании его над определенным элементом происходило какое-нибудь действие? Просто dragdrop видел. А чтобы при окончании перетаскивания что-то происходило нет.
Например алертом вывести имя перетаскиваемого элемента.

Comment: скорее всего в том плагине тоже есть колбэк на это событие. Изучи его документацию. Также посмотри на npmjs.org или на гитхабе

Comment: Отличное [руководство](https://learn.javascript.ru/drag-and-drop-objects), которое не требует подключения дополнительных библиотек.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function () {
    $('.draggable').draggable({ revert: true });
    $('#layout').droppable({
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '/handler/' + $(ui.draggable).attr("id"),
                success: function (data) {

                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

вот нашел нужный мне пример. Но почему он не отправляет ajax ?